# bloginfo(); outputs wrong urls without https on inner pages

Tags: links, https

Template header has lines like this `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/icons/favicon.ico">`

The problem is that `bloginfo('template_directory')` and other functions that use `site_url` (`get_template_uri` etc.) output url with HTTP instead of HTTPS. It happens on every page excepting index page. On the main page urls are correct, with https.

So inner pages are broken because of mixed content.

Site home and wp home in settings are set to `https://example.net`. All http links in database are replaced with https links. Nothing hepled.

What else should I check?

Answer (score 0):

[According to documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri), `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` should check for SSL while retrieving the theme directory url.

Try exchanging `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/icons/favicon.ico">` 
to `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/icons/favicon.ico">` in your header.php file.

Comment: So how it can help me?

Comment: Edited the answer.